# quadratic equations on 2 by 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

For real non-zero $2\times 2$ matrices, can we say:

> For any $A,B$, there are at most two matrices $X$ such that $XX + AX + B =0$

Is there a way to see this without going in the direction of writing the open form result of $XX + AX + B$ and solve each element is equal to zero, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. E.g. over $\mathbb R$, we have $\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&-1}^2=I$ for any $t$. It also follows that
$$
\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&-1}^2+\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&-1}+\pmatrix{-1&0\\ 0&0}=0
$$
for any $t$.

**Edit.** Another counterexample (inspired by Dietrich Burde's answer). Let $u,v$ be any two vectors such that $v^Tu=0$. Then $X=uv^T$ is a solution to the equation $X^2=0$. In particular, if the underlying field is $GF(2)$ (the field consisting of only two elements $0$ and $1$, with $1+1=0$), the equation $Y^2=0$ for a $2\times2$ matrix $Y$ has exactly **four** solutions
$$
Y\in\left\{\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&0},\ \pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\ \pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0},\ \pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}\right\}.
$$
And so does the equation $X^2=I$ over $GF(2)$: just put $X=Y+I$.

Comment: how did you come up with this so fast? may I ask your technique?

Comment: @independentvariable It may not be hard for someone to figure out a counterexample, but I just happen to know that $X^2=I$ has infinitely many solutions over a field of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 4):

No, take for example $A=0$ and 
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $X^2=-B$ has no solution, since $X$ is nilpotent, so that $X^2=0$ but $B\neq 0$.

Comment: The matrices are non zero though.

Comment: It doesn't matter really. You can adapt this example with nonzero $A$. Quadratic matrix solutions need not have any solution.

Comment: But the question is about showing it can have more than 2, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought of "at least". So quadratic matrix equations can have no solution, or a number of solutions including infinity. It comes from the fact that the matrix algebra is not commutative.

Comment: Still, good for knowledge :)